# SBT hook into incremental compilation

Tags: sbt, xsbt-web-plugin, webpack-dev-server

Is there a way to hook into incremental compilation? I need to start some process only once when user start some task, and then stop it when task is stopped. Even if it is started with "~", the important point is that process should not be restarted on each recompilation.

To be more precise, I want to start [webpack dev server](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) only once together with [~container:start](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin#production-approximation). And do not restart webpack on each container restart.

Comment: So when you do container:start without incremental compilation you don't want the server to start?

Comment: hm, actually a good question. I think I want to. I've updated the question.

Comment: You can run `container:start` followed by `compile`, and it will not cause the container process to restart.  You can then run `container:stop` when you're ready to kill the container process.

Comment: Hello, have you resolved issue?